# How do i select the 87% on this page using Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am attempting to scrape some data from this page.

https://www.australiacouncil.gov.au/research/electorate-profiles/wright/#!Wright

The trouble is I am unable to obtain the 87% using BeautifulSoup and Python.

When I run:

```py
soup.find("div",{"class":"progress-bar-item progress-bar-item--text "})
```

I get {{perc}} rather than the actual number.

Comment: It is because that "87%" is probably calculated in real time on your machine (vs on the server) via java script. You may want to look into using `selenium`

Comment: Thank you, I thought that may be the case but thought I better check in with the hive mind first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does look dynamically constructed. If going down selenium route you can do the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver

d = webdriver.Chrome(r'path\chromedriver.exe')
d.get('https://www.australiacouncil.gov.au/research/electorate-profiles/wright/#!Wright')
print(d.find_element_by_css_selector('.dzs-progress-bar strong').text)
d.quit()
```

Comment: Worked a treat, thank you.
I added a bit of a time delay to make sure all the elements were loaded and because I already have a bunch of BeautifulSoup logic written I ended up using 
html = d.page_source 
and parsing that into BeautifulSoup.